# Twitter Greasemonkey script to add a "retweet with comment"?

Tags: twitter, greasemonkey, userscripts, retweet

I as wondering if anyone knows a Greasemonkey script which would add a "retweet with comment" to the timelime items. I was looking for something that would have a similar appearance to [tweetfilter](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/49905), with the little buttons added at the end of the tweet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking to recommend or find a Greasemonkey script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Greasemonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/62720) adds a `RT` link to all tweets on [Twitter.com](http://twitter.com/)

It adds the current tweet text in to to your new tweet box prefixed with RT - this will then enable you to add comments to the tweet before posting.

Other third party applications have this functionality built in. For example, [Seesmic Desktop 2](http://seesmic.com/products/desktop) has a `Quote` option which does the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, I have this on my Android phone in tweetcaster. But I was looking for one to work on the website. This is exactly what I was looking for ... thanks!

Comment: The really weird thing is that the *official* twitter *android app* has this too. But not the website!